# Does Fontforge scripting lang accept only single quotes for script-strings (from command line)

Tags: fontforge

Evoking Fontforge scripts should be enclosed in single-quote strings in my experience, for it to work. I couldn't find any information about this, but for me (on a Debian system) the following script (enclosed in double quotes)

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c "Open($1);Print($0)" haydn-11.svg
```

returns

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by George Williams. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Based on sources from 11:21 UTC 24-Sep-2017-ML-D.
 Based on source from git with hash: 
Open: Wrong number of arguments
Called from...
 <command-string>: line 1
```

whereas when I replace the outer quotes with single-quotes

```
$ fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1);Print($0)' haydn-11.svg 

Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by George Williams. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Based on sources from 11:21 UTC 24-Sep-2017-ML-D.
 Based on source from git with hash: 
Open($1);Print($0)
```

it runs as expected. Is this the normal behavior of Fontforge scripting, when run from terminal?